# Silverlight MouseLeftButtonDown event not firing

Tags: silverlight, button, event-handling

I can get `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, and `Click` events to fire, but not `MouseLeftButtonDown` or `MouseLeftButtonUp`.

Here's my XAML

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Dive.Map.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
        <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" MouseLeftButtonDown="LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="asdf" Background="Transparent"  MouseLeftButtonDown="btnTest_MouseLeftButtonDown"></Button>
        </Canvas>
    </UserControl>
```

And here's my code

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnTest_MouseLeftButtonDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        btnTest.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Button` control (or more specifically the `ButtonBase` super-class from which it derives) handles the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event itself in order to generate the `Click` event.  Hence you cannot get a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event from the standard `Button`.

Is there a reason you aren't using the `Click` event?

Comment: I have a button that acts as a drag and drop handle. I wanted to detect when a user pushed down on the button so then I could start repositioning my control during the MouseMove, and then stop repositioning on the MouseUp event. What should I do instead?

Comment: @Matt: Stop using a button for a drag and drop handle?  It really depends on __why__ you want this.  For example if you are creating some kind of UI builder then you would place the button in a Grid which also has a transparent canvas covering the button.  Then you can manage the events on the canvas.  Note the Canvas and the button would be siblings, the button would not be a child of the Canvas.

Comment: Cool. I ended up creating a content template for my button and then listened for the MouseDown/MouseUp events on the ControlTemplate elements.

Answer (score 4):

If you add the handlers with code like this:

```
    dgv.AddHandler(DataGrid.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(dgv_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
    dgv.AddHandler(DataGrid.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(dgv_MouseLeftButtonUp), true);
```

and make sure you pass true in the last argument "HandledEventsToo" I think you will get it to work - I did...

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever noticed that the MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp events are not fired when a Silverlight button is clicked? The reason for this is that the button handles these two events itself by overriding the OnMouseLeftButtonDown and the OnMouseLeftButtonUp handlers. In the OnMouseLeftButtonDown override, the Click event is raised and the MouseLeftButtonDown event is marked as handled so it couldn't bubble in the visual tree. The OnMouseLeftButtonUp override also marks the MouseLeftButtonUp as handled.

**This thing can be changed using the ClickMode property of the Button control. It has the following values - Hover, Press, Release. The default one is Pressed and we have already explained it. When we have ClickMode set to Release, the Click event will be raised in the OnMouseLeftButtonUp override and the MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp events will be handled inside the button again. If we set the ClickMode to Hover, the Click event will be raised with the MouseEnter event and we will also be able to use the mouse button events.**